# Indexing database with iFilter & full text search in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, database, indexing, full-text-search

I want to use iFilter in order to index txt, microsoft office and PDF documents in my system to be able to search through their contents. I have worked around this **code project** [example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/fulltextsearchingifinters.aspx) and all seems okay.
However, in the database design of my system, the files won't be in the database themselves. Instead i'm only storing the **directories** of the documents in a table called Documents.
My question is **How should I apply iFilter now while the documents are not actually in the database to index?**
is there a way to apply **SQL Full Text Search** with iFilter on the content of a directory instead of the content of byte arrays?

Comment: Sql Full Text Search is tightly coupled with database data in table columsn. But if you just want to use IFilter on files somewhere on the disk, you don't need SQL Server.

Comment: Check Lucene.Net don't know if it will help you in your situation. Anyway full text search only works then documents are stored in table.